# Plugin uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding

Tags: flutter, dart, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

> The plugin `geocoder` uses a deprecated version of the Android
> embedding. To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build
> failures, try to see if this plugin supports the Android V2 embedding.
> Otherwise, consider removing it since a future release of Flutter will
> remove these deprecated APIs. If you are plugin author, take a look at
> the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding:
> https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.

how can I solve this geocoder error that I am facing on runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Migrate the plugin `geocoder` to V2 embedding or change plugin.